# Why switch to the singular in Sh'mot 17:3?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, beshalach

In parshat B'shalach, the people complain a bunch. They do so in the plural form unless the verb is connected to their identity as a nation, a collective singular. However, in 17:3, the text moves back to the singular in the middle of the complain which begins in the plural:

> וַיִּצְמָ֨א שָׁ֤ם הָעָם֙ לַמַּ֔יִם וַיָּ֥לֶן הָעָ֖ם עַל־מֹשֶׁ֑ה וַיֹּ֗אמֶר לָ֤מָּה זֶּה֙ **הֶעֱלִיתָ֣נוּ** מִמִּצְרַ֔יִם לְהָמִ֥ית **אֹתִ֛י** וְאֶת־בָּנַ֥י וְאֶת־מִקְנַ֖י בַּצָּמָֽא

The text could have stayed in the plural (us, our sons and our flocks) but instead expresses this as the singular, "me, my sons and my flocks". The translation at [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.17.3?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) renders this as the plural but I don't see why it wouldn't have then been written in the plural.

Note -- 16:3 is in the plural all the way through, as is 15:24 so I thought it had something to do with unity as a people, but it isn't consistent enough to correlate to some sort of national status.

Comment: What do you see as problematic? The nation, meaning those who are counted as the 600,000 who make up the nation at that time, are referred to in the singular (אותי). Those elements which don’t count as the nation but belong to it, meaning those who are underage (ואת בני) and the property (ואת מקני) are also in danger. So that is why the verb is plural (והעליתנו) first and changes back to singular. The possessions are part of, meaning nullified to, the nation.

Answer (score 4):

The Haamek Daver (also known as the Netziv) addresses this in his commentary to that verse. I bolded the relevant part:

> למה זה העליתנו ממצרים להמית אותי. לא אמרו הוצאתנו ממצרים כלשון התלונה לעיל י״ד י״א ט״ז ג׳. דבאמת כבר האמינו בה׳ שברצונו ית׳ יצאו וכמש״כ לעיל בתלונה שלפני המן. אלא התלוננו על משה שבסיבתו כולם מתנהגים למעלה מן הטבע כאשר כן הוא באמת ומש״ה מי שאינו ראוי למעלה זו שנדרשת זהירות יתירה הרי הוא חסר צרכיו וזה גורם להמית אותי וגו׳. **ומש״ה החלו בל״ר העליתנו היינו כל הקהל וסיימו בל״י להמית אותי היינו כל יחיד המתלונן על עצמו**. ובזה מובן מה שכאן התלוננו על משה לבדו ולא על אהרן משום שהבינו שרק מדת משה הביאם לזה:

Comment: But why make the switch here? The grammar would point to this logical conclusion (it switched to singular because individuals complained for themselves) but why did that happen here (and why, then, would other translations not reflect this accurate grammatical point)?